# PHP preg_split, split by same characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I'm trying to split a string with preg_split. Here's an example of the string:
`111235622411`
I want the output to be like this:

```
$arr[0] = "111";
$arr[1] = "2";
$arr[2] = "3";
$arr[3] = "5";
$arr[4] = "6";
$arr[5] = "22";
$arr[6] = "4";
$arr[7] = "11";
```

So if there's the same characters one after the other, I want them in the same "chunk". I just can't come up with the regular expression I should use. I'm sorry if some of the terms are wrong, because it has been some time since I coded PHP before.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `preg_match_all()`:

```
$string = '111235622411';

preg_match_all('/(.)\1*/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

`\1` references the previously captured group `(.)` (any single character). This feature is called [back referencing](http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.back-references.php). The regex repeats the previously matched character - greedy `*` meaning it matches as much equal characters as possible, what was desired in the question.

Output:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "111"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "6"
  [5]=>
  string(2) "22"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [7]=>
  string(2) "11"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
(.)(?=\1)\1+|\d
```

And instead of splitting it, take the matches.

```
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match_all('/(.)(?=\\1)\\1+|\\d/', '111235622411', $matches);
```

And the `$matches[0]` will contain what you want. As @hek2mgl has suggested, you can also use the simpler `/(\d)\1*/`

[**DEMO**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/15b7f0472940b40f585fae88b7f2d5b357d5f947)

Answer (score 0):

Following, a simple solution that consists in executing a preg_match_all:

The regex in this case is:

```
(\d)\1*
```

Signification of the regex:

- (\d): 1st Capturing group. \d match a digit [0-9].
- \1 matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group.
- *: Quantifier between zero and unlimited times.

The php code would be:

```
$re = "/(\\d)\\1*/"; 
$str = "111235622411"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

You can access for example the first matching group which is "111" like this: $matches[0][0], the second which is "2" like this $matches[0][1], and so on. Check here [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d64c579583567af6df77529c8f49690878836af3) to see a working example.

---

Hope it's useful!